# Is "Waldengard" a German word and if so what does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across this word in the MMO Lotro and I suspect it may be a German word, but I'm not sure. If it is, I'd love to know what it means. My poor guess is something like "forest defender."

Comment: 1. Please give us more context. Write the whole sentence in which you found this word. 2. What is "MMO"? Please don't use abbreviations that are not well known to everybody.

Comment: Looks like a mix of German/Swedish. German _Wald_ means _forest_, Swedish [_gård_](https://de.langenscheidt.com/schwedisch-deutsch/g%C3%A5rd) means German _Hof/Gut/Gehöft_ (_farm/property)_. Found also the Swedish rally driver [Björn Waldegård](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bj%C3%B6rn_Waldeg%C3%A5rd).

Comment: 1. There is no sentence. It's just a stand-alone word, being a title from a deed that you can list next to your character's name. 2. There's something called Google you can use to find out what an MMO is. It's not an esoteric acronym at all. I also gave you the acronym of the game, which would enable you to find out more.

Comment: @Thorongil: I don't think people are more likely to answer by not giving as much information as possible in your question. While I know what an MMO is, you cannot expect people in a language community to know. FYI (sic!): Hubert is one of the top contributers here, and likely would have given you an elaborate answer. But I doubt that he will be encouraged by you saying "Google it, I am too lazy to edit my question, I just want an answer".

Comment: Well, there's something called Google you can use to find out what "Waldengard" is.

Comment: Ranger? <!-- padding padding-->

Answer (score 5):

It's not a *common noun* (= normal word). In the realm of its fantasy world it's probably a *proper noun* (= name). It was probably chosen to evoke precisely the sort of association that you're experiencing. Please note, however, that while "Wald" is a German root meaning "forest", "gard" isn't, so the desired effect really only works on speakers of English with a vague familiarity with German - not on actual speakers of German.

Alternatively, "-gard" is an old Germanic root meaning "yard, enclosure", as in "Midgard", and this may also have influenced the choice.

Comment: There are [many German given names that end with "-gard"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_deutscher_Vornamen_germanischer_Herkunft). Most of them seem extremely rare to me, but at least _Hildegard_ and _Irmgard_ should be commonly known, so _Waldengard_ sounds a bit familiar. Note that Wikipedia even lists _Waldgard_, but without further reference.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a German word according to the official dictionary (The "Duden").

Comment: There is no official list of all German words and also no official dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Is is not a german word I've come across, and it is not in any reference material I have access to.